# cannot import or require node modules (using npm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, import, requirejs

### Versions

I am working on a relatively old Laravel 7 project.

```
npm -v
8.15.0

node -v
v14.17.1
```

### The Issue

I installed a new package using npm

```
npm i my_new_package
```

and am now trying to import the package from my js:

```html
<script type="module" src="/js/filename.js"></script>
```

filename.js:

```js
import { Roulette } from "my_new_package";

// Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@theblindhawk/roulette".
// Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

```js
const Roulette = require("my_new_package");

// Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I tried a bunch of stuff from other SO questions, but none of it seemed to work.
There were no issues when I tried creating a file in the same repository and calling it.

```
import { Roulette } from "./different_file.js";
```

I am guessing this has to do with CommonJS/ES6, but my knowledge about these is quite lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up at the very basics...
Probably cuz I was recently working on a Laravel project with an different file creation method.
I forgot I had to put my js files in the resouces folder, then call them from the `webpack.mix.js`.
The webpack file:

```
mix.js('resources/js/filename.js', 'public/js')
```

Then run `npm run watch` and it will create the files inside the public folder for you.